# GLSL: is it an error to use a non-multisampled texture with a sampler2DMS

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, multisampling

I have an app that may run either with or without multisampling. I am fetching samples from previously rendered multisample textures in a shader. Is it necessary to compile different versions of the shader, either with a sampler2D or a sampler2DMS to access the texture, depending on whether it is a multisample texture or not?

I tried to fetch from a non-multisampled texture through a sampler2DMS and it works, but I don't know if this is undefined behaviour according to the specification, or how much I can rely on this to work.

Does anyone know whether this is propperly defined behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Every texture object you create [has target associated with it](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Theory). When you first bound that object to the context, you passed `glBindTexture` a specific target enum. `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`, etc. The target you use in your first bind call becomes inextricably linked to the texture object; if you try to bind it with a different target, `glBindTexture` will *fail*.

`GL_TEXTURE_2D` and `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE` are *different* targets. If you bind a newly created texture object with `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, obj)`, you *cannot* later bind it with `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`. And vice-versa.

[GLSL samplers types](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Sampler_types), as you may have noticed, have suffixes on them. Well, those suffixes denote the type of texture that the particular sampler type works with. `sampler2D` is a floating-point sampler that works with `GL_TEXTURE_2D` textures. It will therefore only find a texture with the corresponding target.

If you set a `sampler2D` uniform to use texture unit 0, and bind somethign to `GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE`, that sampler *will not see it*. It will only look for a `GL_TEXTURE_2D` bound to that sampler.

Now, you may have heard of [view textures](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/View_Texture). These are textures which share storage with other textures. But the view can have different dimensions and even texture targets. You can view a single layer from a 2D array texture as a 2D texture. And so forth.

Among the conversions that you *cannot* do is view a multisample texture as a non-multisample texture. Or vice-versa.

So if what you described worked, it was undefined behavior. And you cannot rely on it.

That being said:

> Is it necessary to compile different versions of the shader

No; you just can't use *one* variable. It's perfectly valid to have two sampler variables of different types and conditionally decide to sample one vs. the other. If the condition is dynamically uniform (for GL 4.x), you [won't even lose your implicit derivatives](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Non-uniform_flow_control)

The only thing you have to do is make them use *different* texture units. Don't try to play games where you assign them the same texture unit and have it decide which to use based on what you bound. It doesn't work (or if it does, it's UB).

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. Do you happen to know if uniform branching in the fragment shader is as performant as compiling two different shaders? (considering that only one version will be used during program execution, so no additional program binds)